# webgl - objects disappear when rotating camera

Tags: javascript, camera, rotation, webgl, coordinate-transformation

I made a lot of objects randomly, which rotate on their own. I have also tried to implement moving camera. The camera does move left and right, and forward / backwards. The problems is, that if I go to far backwards, my objects slowly start to disappear.

```
mat4.identity(mvMatrix); 

mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(-pitch), [0, 0, 1]);
mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(-yaw), [0, 1, 0]);

mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [-xPosition, -yPosition, -zPosition]);
```

I calculate pitch and yaw while a certain key is pressed. After I do following code, I draw my objects. What do you think could be wrong? I start drawing my objects like this:

```
mvPushMatrix();     
mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [this.x, this.y, this.z]);
mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(this.rotation), [this.axis[0], this.axis[1], this.axis[2]]);
```

this.x, this.y, this.y are the positions where i draw my object. this.rotation is the factor I rotate my object with and array axis determines around which axis the object rotates around.

Answer (score 2):

> The problems is, that if I go to far backwards, my objects slowly start to disappear.

Your objects are clipped by the far plane of the projection:

The projection matrix describes the mapping from 3D points of a scene, to 2D points of the viewport. It transforms from eye space to the clip space, and the coordinates in the clip space are transformed to the normalized device coordinates (NDC) by dividing with the `w` component of the clip coordinates. The NDC are in range (-1,-1,-1) to (1,1,1).
 Every geometry which is out of the NDC is clipped.

The objects between the near plane and the far plane of the camera frustum are mappend to the range (-1, 1) of the NDC.

**Orthographic Clip Space**

At Orthographic Projection the coordinates in the eye space are linearly mapped to normalized device coordinates.

[image]

**Perspective Clip Space**

At Perspective Projection the projection matrix describes the mapping from 3D points in the world as they are seen from of a pinhole camera, to 2D points of the viewport. 
 The eye space coordinates in the camera frustum (a truncated pyramid) are mapped to a cube (the normalized device coordinates).

[image]

Comment: First of all im really thankful for your answeer. Franqly  I don't know a lot about webgl. I have seen this topic before in the tutorial i have been reading. Yet I still don't know how to fix my code.  Do you have any tips on how to fix / upgrade my code.

Comment: @krnneki You have to increase the distance to the far plane. How do you set up the projection matrix?